# Problemas de funcionamiento del método SetFocus

Tags: vba, ms-access

Problemas con el método SetFocus
Enlace directo a este mensaje aikrana 5 horas 57 minutos a las 11:03 Editar mensaje Editar  Cita aikrana Cita  Responder Respuesta
Buenas,

Tengo alguna duda sobre el método SetFocus

En principio por lo poco que se de access (algo de programación entiendo, C++ y Python)  me debería tener "foco" sobre un Cuadro de Texto al que apunto en la expresión:

Me.searchCode.SetFocus

Y mi pregunta, ya que existen diferentes configuraciones en la Hoja de Propiedades, hay alguna configuración para que SetFocus este activo y funcione correctamente, o algo que impida que el cursor se quede donde estoy apuntando con este método, ya que no va a este campo nunca, salta a otro ( en este caso al que puse en las condicionales al pasar por ellas, pero nunca va a "Me.searchCode.SetFocus" )

Saludos

VBA V.7.1

copio un poco de código:

````
Private Sub searchCode_Exit(Cancel As Integer)

Dim sql As String
Dim sql2 As String

   If machine.Value = "UW-F4" Then

    If Not IsNull(searchCode.Value) Then           
            
    
             sql = "Select Description From ErrorLogsUWF4 Where Error Like '" & Me.searchCode.Value & "' Order by id"
                          
             Me.List3.RowSource = sql
             
             sql2 = "Select Unit From ErrorLogsUWF4 Where Error Like '" & Me.searchCode.Value & "' Order by id"
                          
             Me.Lista17.RowSource = sql2
             
            searchCode.BorderColor = vbWhite
    
             
            Else

            If IsNull(searchCode.Value) Then
                Me.searchCode.BorderColor = vbRed
                Me.searchCode.SetFocus
           
        End If
    
    End If
    
   
    
End If
    
If machine.Value = "BRM-10" Then

    If Not IsNull(searchCode.Value) Then

    
        sql = "Select Description From ErrorLogsBRM10 Where Error Like '" & Me.searchCode.Value & "' Order by id"
                              
                 Me.List3.RowSource = sql
                 
                 sql2 = "Select Unit From ErrorLogsBRM10 Where Error Like '" & Me.searchCode.Value & "' Order by id"
                              
                 Me.Lista17.RowSource = sql2
                 
                 
                 
    
    End If
    
End If

Me.searchCode.SetFocus
```


End Sub
````

Comment: Hace mucho que no toco vba pero... no deberías ponerle paréntesis a las funciones? `Me.searchCode.SetFocus()`?

Comment: Yo estoy empezando en access, pero sí debe ser que hace tiempo que no lo tocas, si acritud eh! ;-) SetFocus es un método y no una función

Comment: La idea es volver a ese campo y seguir metiendo búsquedas, en lugar de coger el ratón y clickear sobre él para volver a meter otro dato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me la voy a jugar.

Tu código está en el evento `Exit`:

`Private Sub searchCode_Exit(Cancel As Integer)`

Este evento se produce **justo antes** de que el control pierda el foco.

[Evento TextBox.Exit (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/access.textbox.exit)

Básicamente VBA está ejecutando todo el código **antes** de perder el foco, con lo que tu última línea le pone el foco para luego quitárselo todo seguido.

Parece más un problema de en qué evento poner el código que del propio código.

Prueba a poner al principio del código `Cancel=True`

Comment: Efectivamente, el problema no era el Código en sí, si no donde colocarlo, si te hubiera leído hace unos días lo hubiera solucionado antes, ayer di con ello. Coloque el setFocus antes de salir de otro campo como era el de imprimir los resultados por pantalla, y Voilà! Solucionado

Gracias a todos por vuestras respuestas

Comment: Elimino un problema y su solución me provoca otro. Al darle setFocus  al campo serchCode desde un campo X, me funciona bien, pero que pasa si alguien hace foco con el ratón clickeandoel campo X? Se me va indefinidamente  en un bucle infinito a searchCode y no sale de ahí y no me deja hacer nada, por lo tanto = "administrador de tareas, finalizar access" Alguna otra idea?

Comment: @Aikrana Mejor abre otra pregunta con la duda y pon cómo está configurado todo para resolverlo. Pero suena a que deberías usar una variable global

Comment: Muchas vueltas para encontrar la solución, y debido a mi escaso conocimiento en access, era tan simple como quitarle a todos los campos la opción de Tabulación. Gracias nuevamente